# Ponicode location setting

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, location

I have the issue with Ponicode when try to set the location of test file on the `__tests__` folder.

And I had followed the tutorial on this link [Ponicode Test Location](https://ponicode.github.io/#/ut_extension/gui_test/configuration/testLocation).

But it's not working. That keeping generate the test file on the same location with my source code.

My Node version: 14.18

My `settings.json` file:

```
  ...
  "ponicode.testSettings.testLocation.locationType": "In folder __tests__ at workspace root",
  "ponicode.testSettings.testLocation.path": "{rootDir}/__tests__/{filePath}/{fileName}.test.{ext}"
  ...
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, it turns out that the settings of workspace overwrite my setting of User, which is in `.vscode/settings.json`, just put the same configuration in `.vscode/settings.json`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).